# Previously Installed Anaconda Site Packages Not Working

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, anaconda, python-3.4, jupyter-notebook

I am running into an issue where default site packages are no longer working in a jupyter notebook.  However, when I send a script to the computer via windows cmd to install pip "package name", the package works again.  Site Packages were working properly prior to yesterday.  This is what changed:

Yesterday, I ran a script via windows cmd to install a few packages and to activate a few widget extension in the jupyter notebook.  Because I ran the script within windows cmd, could windows shell be taking precedence over the anaconda shell?

Troubleshooting: For the default packages that were note working, I reran the install pip "package name" in a windows shell and the package started working again, along with the new packages I installed yesterday with windows cmd.

When I look in c:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages the modified date for the "reinstalled" packages shows the original date that I installed the software.

This software is very new to me and I am still trying to learn the logic of it along with the process.  Any help or recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

OS: Windows 7 64-bit
[Software: Python 3.5.2 (Anaconda3 4.1.1 64-Bit)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5Qhf.jpg)

Comment: Did you unintsall anaconda and reinstalled it? Also first update the anaconda from cmd after installing it. Here is the link of the website which tells you how to setup ananconda, I recommend you to go through it first. [https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install)

Comment: No, Anaconda was not reinstalled.  It has only been installed once and that was during the summer of 2016.  I will update anaconda on one machine to see if that fixes the issue.  Right now I have about 32 machines that this is happening to.